# jQuery Sequential CSS Animation with .wait and .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am coding a simple Simon Says game and trying to animate the four game tiles with a sequence of "presses". A press is simply a decrease and then increase in the opacity of this tile. Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thmsdnnr/ru0b73vq/6/

```
function playSequence(seq) {
  var idTranslate=["","#red","#green","#blue","#yellow"];
  for (var i=0;i<seq.length;i++) {
  var selector=idTranslate[seq[i]];
  $(selector).delay(500*i).animate({opacity: 0.4},100).animate({opacity: 1.0},350);
  }
}
```

I call this for testing with:

```
var testSeq = [1,2,3,4,4,2,1];
playSequence(testSeq);
```

The code works fine, until it gets to the second instance of tile 4 at index 4 of the array. Strangely, it hangs, then appears to "press" tile 2 (index 5) and then 1 (index 6) very quickly, and then to press tile 4 at the very *end* of the animation instead of in between.

I can't tell why the animation is getting hung up here. The same behavior happens any time I try to press the same tile more than once, regardless of the test sequence I use (e.g., testSeq=[1,2,1,1,4];).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use the .delay(), I've forked your fiddle and used the setTimeout(). [Take a look at it here](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/6ubajmxm/), see if it does what you're looking for. Something about the stacked delays on the divs is causing some odd addition, if I had to hazard a guess.

```html
playAnim = function(el, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.animate({
      opacity: 0.4
    }, 100).animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    }, 350)

  }, delay)
}
```

Comment: This works fantastic. Was my original code was just a bad design pattern or poor method choice? I've been reading jQuery documentation and trying to figure out exactly why it was misbehaving in the way that it was. I'm still so new to this stuff though that I might be overlooking something dumb. Maybe I just shouldn't have chosen .delay(). Most sites say "just use setTimeout()". Maybe just accept and move on! :)

Comment: It seems there was an odd glitch when calling delay() on an element multiple times. It might be an interesting experiment to determine what exactly was happening (my guess was the delay() was being stacked, so after the first delay countdown finished the second one started), but the setTimeout was a quick and simple fix.